# Finite covering of linear simisimple Lie group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple real Lie group such that there exits a linear semisimple 
Lie group $\tilde G$  that finitely covers $G$. Is $G$ also linear?

Comment: Yes it's true: a quotient of a linear algebraic group by a finite normal subgroup is still linear. I'm not sure of a proof by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a simpler proof in the case of finite normal subgroups, but here is a general theorem, see Theorem 11.5 in

J.Humphreys, "Linear Algebraic Groups."

**Theorem.** Suppose that $G$ is an algebraic linear Lie group, $H\triangleleft G$ is a closed normal subgroup. Then $G/H$  is again linear.

In your case, you can replace your $G$ with its (Zariski) closure and use the fact that finite groups are closed.